# What have I done wrong with my Sine Oscillator circuit schematic in LTspice

Tags: oscillator, ltspice, simulation, sine

How do I improve my circuit schematic so that I obtain the desired result in LTSpice?

I have recreated a circuit of a Sine oscillator from a textbook. However, when I simulate it, the result is different to what is expected.

I have compared the 2 schematics and they are similar in every sense. The only difference is that the Textbook specifies a Philips NPN transistor and my library only contains a NXP equivalent.

Any insight that anyone can provide will be very much appreciated.

[image: Textbook schematic]

[image: Textbook result]

[image: My LTSpice schematic]

[image: My LTSpice result]

Comment: Philips sold off their semiconductor division ... as NXP.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!! I was thinking something similar, but couldn't understand why some of the transistors still bear the Philips name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've noted the differences in your circuits in the images below:

[image]

- The resistor notated as R5 is different by 10 fold
- There is a connection between capacitors C1 and C4 that shouldn't be there

Comment: Spot on, unlike OP's "similar in every sense".

Comment: Thanks very much for the spot, especially with regards to the connection between C1 and C4. The resistor value itself is not the cause of the issue, as I've accidentally uploaded a latter version of the circuit with a greater resistance that helps to smooth out the output.

Comment: By the way, do I receive a score for my question? :)

Comment: I had already upvoted it ;-)